# Spoof network traffic IP

Tags: networking, android

I'm from Argentina. Here we use WhatsApp as our main mobile communication method. Because of that, for the last two years, local mobile carriers started making WhatsApp traffic free and unlimited, aside of one's data plan.
So I was thinking, could there be a way to spoof my Android's network traffic's IP or something like that, in order to make my carrier think I'm using WhatsApp instead of (for example) YouTube, and consequently make all my traffic free?

Comment: Please let me know if I didn't explain myself properly. I'm not good at spontaneous English...

Answer (score 0):

**No.**  Your (source) IP addresses is allocated by your carrier.  Their network likely has filters that would prevent traffic from different addresses from travelling across their network.

The destination addresses would need to be within the range the carrier specifies for free billing purposes, which would likely be WhatsApp's own registered ASN / IP range, unless, say, WhatsApp was co-locating with your carrier, in which case your connection to WhatsApp wasn't actually leaving the carrier's network at all.

However, if you wanted to explore any gap from the carrier's rule you could investigate the following:

- IP Source Routing - the IP packet can contain an instruction for the router at the destination to forward the packet on to another address (this is often disabled on routers)
- Finding a co-location provider that uses IP address space near, or shares with WhatsApp.  If you put a proxy server on a nearby address, it might not be caught by the carrier's rule.
- Have a friend at WhatsApp set you up a proxy server or VPN on one of their hosts.

These are all highly unlikely to work...

Comment: The question seems to be about spoofing the _destination_ addresses.

Comment: The answer's still no - just the explanation is different ;)

Comment: @grawity added some background to destination addressing